# Remove inline XML tags from strings without adding spaces

Tags: xslt

I have looked but haven't been able to find an answer to this specific problem, but if I'm wrong I apologize.

Basically I have things like this all over my XML:

```
<some-text>
   Here is something interesting<em>/</em>cool to look at
</some-text>
```

I want to get the text but remove the "em" tags without replacing them with a space so that I end up with:

*Here is something interesting/cool to look at*

and not:

*Here is something interesting / cool to look at*

Note: I am using xslt 2.0 and this isn't just in one tag, it's document wide, so I need a solution to remove them from all over.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a way to distinguish the tags you want to remove from those you want to keep.

Comment: It would be better to show us your existing code, because if it's inserting spaces then it's wrong, and it would be nice to know what mistake you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following template with Saxon:

```
<xsl:template match="em">
    <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is without (unwanted) spaces.
This works in combination with the *identity template*

```
<!-- Identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The identity template replicates (nearly) the whole XML. Here except for the `<em>` tags which are matched and reduced to their text value by the first template.